# Allow users with is_request 1 to not log in

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am currently working on a system where people can submit a registration request. The admin will need to accept the request in order for the user to be able to sign in. In my database, I have a field called `is_request` and with every registration this field is set by default to 1 (is set by default to 1 in the database) , meaning yes. When a user with this field set to 1, tries to log in, they will need to be notified that their account has not yet been activated. How can I accomplish this?

When the user tries to register the following happens:

```php
protected function create(array $data)
    {
        $users = User::where('role_id', 1)->get();

        $user = User::create([
            'firstname' => $data['firstname'],
            'lastname' => $data['lastname'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'role_id' => 3,
            'activated' => 0,
            'user_token' => Str::random(32),
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);

        foreach($users as $admin) {
            $admin->notify(new registerRequest($user));
        }

        Mail::to($user->email)->send(new RegisterRequestSend($user));

        return $user;
    }
```

And when the admin in the backend "accepts" the request the field `is_request` will be set to 0 and the user needs to be able to sign into the app.

The login controller looks like this

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
}
```

Update:: DB Table
[image]

Comment: That is how you can do easy way switch statement or if statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create an global middleware that checks if the user is accepted or not:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class CheckIfAccepted
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (auth()->check() && !auth()->user()->isAccepted) {
            auth()->logout();

            return redirect('not-accepted');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

This middleware will log out any authed user that aren't accepted and redirect them to a route of your choice.

Change `auth()->user()->isAccepted` to an attribute or method that contains information about the accepted-status.

If you want the middleware to run at every request, you can add it as a global middleware by adding it the the `$middleware`-array in `app/Http/Kernel.php`.

You can read more about middleware and how to create them in the docs:
https://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware

Comment: Thank you KFoobar this is the answer I was looking for. How can I implement this or is adding it to `Kernel.php` enough?

Comment: @Rainierlaan Adding it to `Kernel.php` should be enough. I also edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to make the admin to update the attributes of the user when they are notified

```
User::where('id' , $user_id)->update(['is_request' => 0]);
```

then add this in your login controller

```
public function credentials(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->only($this->username(), 'password');
        $credentials = array_add($credentials, 'is_request', 0);
        return $credentials;
    }
```

Comment: You can assume there is always an admin. How can this be implemented? I don't see the link?